# React Native code behave differently on iPhone X simulator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, iphone-x

I am using react navigation 2 with React native to build an Authentication flow (following this [tutorial](https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v2)).

The application works fine when I run it in the iPhone 6s simulator.
The app directs me to the Welcome screen as no *userToken* is found in *AsyncStorage*.

My code is the following:

**AuthLoadingScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native'


export default class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.loadApp()
  }
  // Remember logged in user
  loadApp = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#fff" />
      </View>     
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#aa73b7',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

**WelcomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'


export default class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>WelcomeScreen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#aa73b7',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

**App.js**

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import WelcomeScreen from './src/components/screens/WelcomeScreen'
import AuthLoadingScreen from './src/components/screens/AuthLoadingScreen'


const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
})

export default createSwitchNavigator({
  Authloading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStackNavigator
})
```

However, when I run the following app in the iPhone X simulator, it keeps showing the activity indicator instead of directing me to the welcome screen (the expected behavior).

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `this.loadApp()` in `componentDidMount` instead of `constructor` it should work.

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Can you please elaborate on the cause of this?

Comment: The constructor is often for initializing object internal state componentDidMount is a lifecycle method that comes right after the component is fully Mounted, i guess the reason why It didn't work in your case is the object is not yet initialized.

Comment: Can you please try it again in in the `constructor` but this time add props like this `constructor(props) { super(props); this.loadApp() }` this also should work. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

***this.loadApp()*** should be removed from ***constructor***. Place it in a lifecycle hook like ***componentDidMount()*** so that it should be called after component completes mounting.

**You can do this for some method and function calls** : this is what constructors are for. Like mostly bind functions are called inside constructor(Best practice). Also you make it clear that the object is never constructed in an unknown state (without configuration loaded).

**You shouldn't because your object is not initalized** : calling instance method in constructor is dangerous because the object is not yet fully initialized (this applies mainly to methods than can be overridden).